# What is the equivalent to django.conf.global_settings for third-party apps?

Tags: django, django-settings, django-apps

For Django itself, settings mostly have default values, defined in `django.conf.global_settings`.

What should a third-party app do instead? (And ideally, why?)

1. Modify `django.conf.global_settings`? (A brief look at `django/conf/__init__.py` suggests this wouldn't work as the values are loaded into the `Settings` object as soon as a setting is accessed, which will obviously have happened before a third-party app is loaded.)
2. Modify the `settings` object in e.g. `myapp/__init__.py`?

   ```
   if not hasattr(django.conf.settings, 'MY_SETTING'):
       django.conf.settings.MY_SETTING = 'default'
   ```
3. Have a separate module, e.g. `myapp.conf`, which gets the values statically?

   ```
   MY_SETTING = getattr(django.conf.settings, 'MY_SETTING', 'default')
   ```
4. Have a separate module, e.g. `myapp.conf`, which provides functions to get the values?

   ```
   def my_setting():
       return getattr(django.conf.settings, 'MY_SETTING', 'default')
   ```
5. Something like 3 or 4, but not in a separate module?
6. Something else I haven't thought of?

At present doing both 1 and 2 looks to me to be the best, as it gets it to truly be a regular setting, plus it'll then work with `manage.py diffsettings` (c.f. `django.core.management.commands.diffsettings`, it compares `global_settings` with `settings` to arrive at its decision on what is different).

Comment: Most 3rd party apps I've used use approach 3 ([here's an example with django-facebook](https://github.com/tschellenbach/Django-facebook/blob/master/django_facebook/settings.py)). You can check out [django-appconf](https://github.com/jezdez/django-appconf) though for an approach similar to 4

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony: my vague feeling is that #3 is probably the most prevalent, but #1 + #2 feels better (see the last paragraph which I've just added)

Comment: #1 requires changing Django core source code (which should sound horrible to you), for #2 the "online" change to the `settings` object sounds scary to me as it should be a constant, really. #3 and #4 will work with `diffsettings` too as settings not in `global_settings` [will also be shown](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-diffsettings). And why would #3 and #4 not represent a "truly regular setting"?

Comment: @gertvdijk: sorry, by #1 I meant triggering `django.conf.global_settings.MY_SETTING = 'default'` in `myapp/__init__.py` (at least at the app's import time). So long as it's happening at that time, I would fully expect #2 to be safe also. For `diffsettings`, without #1 and #2, it will always show them, which I would not consider to be "correct behaviour"; I would like it to show only when they've changed from their default values, as with core settings. By truly regular I mean that it actually *is* a setting, always; `django.conf.settings.MY_SETTING` will work. Makes third-party code nicer.